# R, layout: How to determine the width of the parts of a plotting region in order to center a title?

Tags: r, layout

I would like to center a title with respect to a plot matrix (and not the overall plot) I created with this code:

```
d <- 3
d2 <- d*d
layout.mat <- matrix(1:d2, byrow=TRUE, ncol=d) # plot matrix
layout.mat <- cbind(layout.mat, rep(0, d)) # space
layout.mat <- cbind(layout.mat, rep(d2+1, d)) # column on the right side
wspace <- 6*par("csi")*2.54 # width of the space in character height in cm
wside <- 3*par("csi")*2.54 # width of the right side in character height in cm
layout(layout.mat, respect=TRUE, widths=c(rep(1, d), lcm(wspace), lcm(wside)))
layout.show(d2+1)
par(mar=rep(0, 4), oma=c(4,4,6,4))
for(i in 1:d){
    for(j in 1:d){
        plot.new()
        plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
        ll <- par("usr")
        rect(ll[1], ll[3], ll[2], ll[4])
        text(0.5, 0.5, paste("i=",i,", j=",j,sep=""), cex=1.4)
    }
}
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
ll <- par("usr")
rect(ll[1], ll[3], ll[2], ll[4])
text(0.5, 0.5, "side", cex=1.4)

## title
mtext("This title should be centered according to the plot matrix", side=3,
      line=2, outer=TRUE, adj=0.5, at=0.5)
```

How can I determine (with given fixed distances `wspace` and `wside`) the width of plot region so that I can subtract `wspace+wside` from it to determine the width of the plot matrix? The ultimate goal is to determine a precise value for `adj` of `mtext` such that the title is centered above the plot matrix and not the overall plotting region.

Comment: Might be a lot easier if you switch to `lattice` or `ggplot` , both of which have tools to lay out a collection of plots for you.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If you look at the OP's history, you'll see they've asked a series of questions about a fairly specific, customized scatterplot matrix in base R, so I'd bet ggplot/lattice aren't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding this code inside your `for` loop:

```
if (i == 1 & j == 2){
   mtext("This title should be centered according to the plot matrix", side=3,
        line=2, outer=FALSE, adj=0.5, at=0.5)
}
```

Note the change to `outer = FALSE`. Here's what it looks like, with shorter title text (the long version runs off either side in a small plot, but is still centered):

[image]

Of course, this hack only works if you have an odd number of columns. A more general solution may be to alter the layout to include a short, wide horizontal region at the top, and plot text in that region directly:

```
d <- 4
d2 <- d*d
layout.mat <- matrix(1:d2, byrow=TRUE, ncol=d) # plot matrix
layout.mat <- cbind(layout.mat, rep(0, d)) # space
layout.mat <- cbind(layout.mat, rep(d2+1, d)) # column on the right side
layout.mat <- rbind(c(rep(18,d),0,0),layout.mat) #Add row on top
wspace <- 6*par("csi")*2.54 # width of the space in character height in cm
wside <- 3*par("csi")*2.54 # width of the right side in character height in cm
#Note adjustments to heights
layout(layout.mat, respect=TRUE, widths=c(rep(1, d), lcm(wspace), lcm(wside)),
       heights = c(0.25,rep(1,nrow(layout.mat)-1)))
layout.show(d2+1)
par(mar=rep(0, 4), oma=c(4,4,6,4))
for(i in 1:d){
    for(j in 1:d){
        plot.new()
        plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
        ll <- par("usr")
        rect(ll[1], ll[3], ll[2], ll[4])
        text(0.5, 0.5, paste("i=",i,", j=",j,sep=""), cex=1.4)
    }
}
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
ll <- par("usr")
rect(ll[1], ll[3], ll[2], ll[4])
text(0.5, 0.5, "side", cex=1.4)

## title
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
ll <- par("usr")
#rect(ll[1], ll[3], ll[2], ll[4])
text(0.5, 0.5, "top", cex=1.4)
```

[image]

Comment: *Brilliant*, joran, many thanks. I put it in my code this way. Thanks for helping. As you see, I followed you idea of using `layout`. The whole plot looks good. Actually, one could even improve both `pairs` and `filled.contour` with these ideas.

Comment: Hi joran, do you know how one can turn of the clipping of the region for the title? The problem is that if the title is to wide, it gets clipped off at both sides.

Comment: @MariusHofert Set `par(xpd = NA)` for just that plotting region.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions.  These can be used to convert between different coordinate systems.  You could use this to find the device coordinates corresponding to the right and left edges of the plotting or figure regions, then use that information to decide where to place the overall title.

Here is an example of one way to do it.  The nice part about this is it can be run after any of the plotting commands (you don't need to create and set up the final plot region at the top but rather put the text into the margin area.

```
#  left edge of matrix
l.x <- grconvertX(0, from='nic')
# right side of matrix (right side of inner minus wspace and wside)
r.x <- grconvertX(grconvertX(1, from='nic', to='inches') - (wspace+wside)/2.54,
    from='inches')

# find 2 line heights from top
t.y <- grconvertY(1, from='ndc') - 2*strheight('Test text')
# or 2 line heights above inner margin
t.y <- grconvertY(1, from='nic') + 2*strheight('Test text')


par(xpd=NA)
text( (l.x+r.x)/2, t.y, 'Test text' )
```

Comment: Dear Greg, thanks for helping. It would be fantastic if you could provide a solution with `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` to the above minimal example.

Comment: I added one simple example, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Many thanks for adding this, Greg. The good thing is that you don't need to change the layout depending on whether a title is given or not. A disadvantage seems to be that, after changing the size of the plot window, one has to run the code again in order for the title to be centered correctly.